# The "chestnut " — is a noun or Pronoun in this context?

Tags: pronouns, nouns

Everyone expected **the chestnut** to win.

I think it's a **noun** but it's pronoun someone said..

Comment: It's a part of a noun phrase ('chestnut racehorse').

Comment: You are right -- it's a noun phrase.

Comment: It's an adjective standing in for a noun phrase (chestnut [coloured] horse).

Comment: No; "chestnut" is a  noun here, used to specify a horse of that colour. See here[link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/chestnut_1?q=chestnut)

Comment: @BillJ - the OED disagrees. See [sense B (as adjective), subsection c - short for chestnut horse](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00037894)

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't think centuries-old classifications are much help. I gave a link in my last comment to the current Oxford Learner's Dictionary, which gives it as a noun. And so does the Cambridge: [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chestnut). Note also that, unlike an adjective, it can be pluralised: "I bought a couple of chestnuts from a local trainer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a noun (or a noun phrase formed from a determiner and a noun)

It's not a pronoun, as it is not one of the words "he, she, it, theirs..." that refer anaphorically (or otherwise) to another noun.  Instead it names or refers to a horse.

It's not an adjective, although it has been formed from an adjective.  It is often possible to take an adjective like "chestnut" and use it as a noun "the chestnut" to mean "the chestnut thing" (and in this context I suppose the "thing" is "horse")

The pronouns in English form a small and closed class of words.  "Chestnut" is not in that class.  One can't use other words as pronouns in the way that one can use nouns as verbs, or adjectives as nouns (for example) So if a word isn't on the list of pronouns, then it isn't a pronoun.